# Silverlight vs. HTML for building Admin Panel?

Tags: html, silverlight

I want to build admin panel for my site!

But, I'm puzzled between Silverlight and HTML.

I believe Silverlight give me greater control and easier from HTML

What do you advise me to use in terms of best, security, and strong controls?

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

In spite of what everyone says, `Silverlight` (and even `Flash`) is not everywhere. There are still a lot of users and browsers that don't have or support `Silverlight`. Of course it will be a great application if built using `Silverlight`, but you cannot just ignore the ones who don't have it installed. If you go with `Silverlight`, you will still need to implement a simple HTML version of your `Admin Panel`.

Having said all of this, it really depends on your user base, scope of your application and the type of environment it is going to run in.

Answer (score 0):

Guess it depends on your audience. For an admin panel, unless you need the maximum reach to various devices and operating systems, Silverlight is probably fine and will probably allow you to whip something together very quickly using RIA services or WCF Data Services.

As far as security goes - you'll want to secure your services the same way regardless of whether you're using a HTML or Silverlight client to access them. Basically, just never assume that your client is the only one accessing your services. Don't send any data down to the client that you wouldn't want exposed and don't trust any input from the client without validating it first. This is where RIA services can help as it can coordinate validation rules on the client and server.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not really familiar with Silverlight so I can't judge anything about it. With regards to html I guess Its a better choice if you want it available in many browser. If you heard about html5 I think you'll have a second thought about it. Well it still base on your needs.